# HLSL : Offset and length were out of bounds

Tags: xna, hlsl

```
//Vertex Shader Constants 
float4x4 World; float4x4 View; float4x4 Projection; float4x4 WorldViewIT;

//Color Texture 
texture Texture;

//Normal Texture
texture NormalMap;

//Specular Texture 
texture SpecularMap;

//Albedo Sampler 
sampler AlbedoSampler = sampler_state 
{ 
    texture = <Texture>;
    MINFILTER = LINEAR;  
    MAGFILTER = LINEAR;  
    MIPFILTER = LINEAR;  
    ADDRESSU = WRAP;  
    ADDRESSV = WRAP; 
};

//NormalMap Sampler 
sampler NormalSampler = sampler_state 
{
texture = <NormalMap>;  
MINFILTER = LINEAR;  
MAGFILTER = LINEAR;  
MIPFILTER = LINEAR;  
ADDRESSU = WRAP;  
ADDRESSV = WRAP; 
};

//SpecularMap Sampler
sampler SpecularSampler = sampler_state { 
texture = <SpecularMap>;  
MINFILTER = LINEAR;  
MAGFILTER = LINEAR;  
MIPFILTER = LINEAR;  
ADDRESSU = WRAP;  
ADDRESSV = WRAP; 
};

//Vertex Input Structure 
struct VSI { 
float4 Position : POSITION0;  
float3 Normal : NORMAL0;  
float2 UV : TEXCOORD0;  
float3 Tangent : TANGENT0;  
float3 BiTangent : BINORMAL0;
};

//Vertex Output Structure 
struct VSO { 
float4 Position : POSITION0; 
float2 UV : TEXCOORD0;  
float3 Depth : TEXCOORD1;
float3x3 TBN : TEXCOORD2;
};

//Vertex Shader 
VSO VS(VSI input) {
//Initialize Output 
VSO output;

//Transform Position  
float4 worldPosition = mul(input.Position, World);
float4 viewPosition = mul(worldPosition, View);
output.Position = mul(viewPosition, Projection);
//Pass Depth  
output.Depth.x = output.Position.z;
output.Depth.y = output.Position.w;
output.Depth.z = viewPosition.z;

//Build TBN Matrix  
output.TBN[0] = normalize(mul(input.Tangent, (float3x3)WorldViewIT));
output.TBN[1] = normalize(mul(input.BiTangent, (float3x3)WorldViewIT));
output.TBN[2] = normalize(mul(input.Normal, (float3x3)WorldViewIT));

//Pass UV  
output.UV = input.UV;

//Return Output  
return output;
}

//Pixel Output Structure 
struct PSO {
float4 Albedo : COLOR0;
float4 Normals : COLOR1;
float4 Depth : COLOR2;
};

//Normal Encoding Function 
half3 encode(half3 n) {
n = normalize(n);

n.xyz = 0.5f * (n.xyz + 1.0f);

return n;
}

//Normal Decoding Function 
half3 decode(half4 enc) { return (2.0f * enc.xyz - 1.0f); }


 //Pixel Shader 
PSO PS(VSO input) {  //Initialize Output  
PSO output;

//Pass Albedo from Texture  
output.Albedo = tex2D(AlbedoSampler, input.UV);
//Pass Extra - Can be whatever you want, in this case will be a Specular Value  
output.Albedo.w = tex2D(SpecularSampler, input.UV).x;

//Read Normal From Texture  
half3 normal = tex2D(NormalSampler, input.UV).xyz * 2.0f - 1.0f;

//Transform Normal to WorldViewSpace from TangentSpace 
normal = normalize(mul(normal, input.TBN));

//Pass Encoded Normal 
output.Normals.xyz = encode(normal);
//Pass this instead to disable normal mapping 
//output.Normals.xyz = encode(normalize(input.TBN[2])); 

 //Pass Extra - Can be whatever you want, in this case will be a Specular Value 
output.Normals.w = tex2D(SpecularSampler, input.UV).y;

//Pass Depth(Screen Space, for lighting) 
output.Depth = input.Depth.x / input.Depth.y;

//Pass Depth(View Space, for SSAO) 
output.Depth.g = input.Depth.z;

//Return Output  
return output;
}

//Technique 
technique Default {
pass p0 {
    VertexShader = compile vs_3_0 VS();
    PixelShader = compile ps_3_0 PS();
}
}
```

This is my current shader… it is producing a "Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater than the number of elements from index to the end of the source collection" argumente axeception… I don't understand what's wrong with it….

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What line produces the error?

Comment: I dont't know… visual studio doens't say.

Comment: A debugging technique: comment everything, and add again only small chunks of code, and see what chunks generates the error. This helps narrow down there the bug is coming from.